# How to see the filesystem of a camera firmware?

Tags: firmware, surveillance, binary-code

I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8DjTcANBx0 and in this video he downloads several camera firmwares and analyzes their files. As far as I know, the firmwares are binary files that you can see with hex editors. But how to I see the files in there?

Comment: It's going to depend on the specific vendor how they implement their software. Some have a simple zip, others are packed, encrypted files. There is no standard everyone abides by

Comment: @Daisetsu in this case it's a .bin file. I know a firmware upgrade could be lots of things, but in the case of a .bin file, how should I discover if there are files inside it?

Comment: the bin extension stands for binary. There is no standard binary file format. It's not like a JPEG where there's a standard which defines the file structure. A bin could be literally anything.

Comment: You're looking to reverse engineer it. See similar https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15065/help-editing-repacking-repackaging-img-wi-fi-camera-firmware

Comment: Questions about reverse engineering should be asked on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might want to look up `binwalk`...

Comment: @forest thanks, that worked and I can already see that the bin firmware has lots os files. However I don't see a way to extract the with this utility. Do you know a way?